# Difference in reponse time of Jmeter and chrome dev tool

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Why i am getting big response time difference between result from JMeter and chrome dev tools. If i am looking at a particular http request's response in chrome dev tool, it is 495 ms while in jmeter, the same http request's average time is 29 ms

Tried diable the cache of chrome devtool and then running the http request's, getting the same difference

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "api"? If it's a matter of a single simple HTTP request - then you need to use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what's going on in each phase of the request.

In case you're trying to compare response time from JMeter with response time of a real browser first of all you need to [ensure that JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of handling embedded resources, [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript running inside of the browser vs running HTTP straight to the web/app server.

Architecture - It's a foundation skill for this field